# Is it 'fitted with' or 'fit with'?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, past-participles, formal-language, word-form

Is it 'fit with' or 'fitted with'? In:

> A stand *fitted with* a protractor

Comment: [Collins dictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fit)  *In American English the form **fit** is used in the present tense and **sometimes also as the past tense and past participle of the verb**.* That's to say, some people align ***fit*** with irregular verbs like ***hit***, where *He **hit*** [Past] *you first, so you **hit*** [Present] *him now.* But most people treat ***to fit*** as a regular verb today, with past tense ***fitted***.

Comment: There's a lot of uncertainty around **??IT** verbs - all of ***shit, shat, shitted*** are used as past tenses, for example, and few people really want to get too deeply involved in which one of *those* is the "right, proper, correct" version! (But from my "descriptive linguistics" perspective, they're all fine! :)

Comment: principle parts: fit, fit, fitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use *fitted with*.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fitted#google_vignette) has an example similar to your question.

> 6. ADJECTIVE [verb-link ADJECTIVE with noun, ADJECTIVE noun]
>    If a room is **fitted with** objects, those objects are in the room and are normally fixed in place.

> Bedrooms are **fitted with** alarm pull cords to alert the manager in an emergency.

Comment: Good answer, btw We can simply say:- a fitted protractor.

Comment: @Sam, or can it be 'a *fit* protractor', LOL?

Answer (score 1):

It means a stand that is or has been fitted (hence the past participle *fitted*) with a protractor. Here *be fitted with* means possess as an attachment, layer, adornment, etc.